# How to excluding some records before left join executes

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm looking for a way to excluding some records before i the left join executes.

My sql statement looks as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM premissions WHERE post_id = 1) AS p
ON p.user_id = users.id
WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

How can I exclude the records with the id 1 and two in the user table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add criteria to your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  *
            FROM    premissions
            WHERE   post_id = 1
           ) AS p 
    ON p.user_id = users.id
WHERE   p.id IS NULL
  AND users.id NOT IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subselect

```
SELECT * FROM
(select * from users where id not in(1,2))
 u 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM premissions WHERE post_id = 1) AS p
ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select from users where id not in (1,2)) u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM premissions WHERE post_id = 1) AS p
ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to filter in where clause or do it as M Khalid Junaid has mentioned.

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM premissions WHERE post_id = 1) AS p
ON p.user_id = users.id
WHERE p.id IS NULL
 and users.id not in (1, 2)
```